# How to make a script to select objects by diffuse_color?

Tags: scripting

I have a file that I imported from the .svg format, there are a lot of curves.
I would like to combine the curves with the same color, how to write a script for this? (Sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

This script is a good start. Describe what you need with more details if you don't know any Python and this isn't enough to get you started.

```
import bpy

my_blue_mat = bpy.data.materials["My_Blue_Mat"]
my_red_mat = bpy.data.materials["My_Red_Mat"]
my_green_mat = bpy.data.materials["My_Green_Mat"]

for obj in bpy.data.objects.keys():
    mat = bpy.data.objects[obj].material_slots.keys()
    for m in mat:
        if bpy.data.materials[m].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value[2] > .4 :
            bpy.data.objects[obj].material_slots[m].material = my_blue_mat
            if not "My" in m:
                bpy.data.materials.remove(bpy.data.materials[m])
        elif bpy.data.materials[m].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value[0] > .4 :
            bpy.data.objects[obj].material_slots[m].material = my_red_mat
            if not "My" in m:
                bpy.data.materials.remove(bpy.data.materials[m])
        elif bpy.data.materials[m].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value[1] > .4 :
            bpy.data.objects[obj].material_slots[m].material = my_green_mat
            if not "My" in m:
                bpy.data.materials.remove(bpy.data.materials[m])
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: I need to: select an object and find objects with the same color and select them and merge into one